# how to use upsert in react native sqlite database

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table in react native SQLite with 2 columns app_name,key

I want to update a value if it exists based on app_name else insert new data I tried the following

```
 db.transaction(function (tx) {
              tx.executeSql(
                'Insert or Ignore Into client_registration (app_name, key) values(?,?); UPDATE client_registration SET app_name=?, key=? where changes() = 0 and "app_name" = ?;',
                ['coin', 123],
                (tx, results) => {
                  if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
                   console.log('success')
                    );
                  } else console.log('Registration Failed');
                },
              );
            });
```

i am unable to ge any output .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite supports [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) with the `ON CONFLICT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO client_registration(app_name, key) VALUES (?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(app_name) DO UPDATE
SET key = EXCLUDED.key;
```

I assume that for `app_name` there is a unique constrain defined in the table.

You will have to check the version of SQLite that your android API level uses, because `UPSERT` was introduced in version 3.24.0

Without the use of `UPSERT` you will have to execute 2 statements in this order:

```
UPDATE client_registration 
SET key=? 
WHERE app_name = ?;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO client_registration(app_name, key) VALUES (?, ?);
```

Comment: cant we do it without upsert? like howi have my query?

Comment: I tried upsert didnt work    'INSERT INTO client_registration(app_name, key) VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT(app_name) DO UPDATE SET key = EXCLUDED.key;',

                [
                 'coin',
                  '123',
                ],

Comment: @user check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b527b4ded1bad9141d6061db8147288f to see that it works. Is there a unique constraint for app_name?

Comment: yes app_name is always said to be unique i should be created if it doesnt exist else update

Comment: @user *should be unique* does not mean that it has a unique constraint. I asked if in the table's definition app_name is defined as the primary key or there is a unique constraint for it. Can you post the table's definition?

Comment: yes it works now it wasnt a primary key sorry for inconvenience

Comment: i can do this for muliple constraints right?  in case i have 3 vals and 2 values need to be unique

Comment: @user inside ON CONFLICT you must enumerate the columns that make the unique constraint, like  ON CONFLICT(column1,column2)

Comment: can we check if a particular value exists in TABLE A then alter table B in sqlite for ex:- table A contains 2 col: name & key if a particular (name & key exists ) then alter table B which may have name,phno,address cols.so if table A query is saisfied then only alter table B

can it be done in a single query? i am new to sql  can you help?@forpas

Comment: @user The comments section is not the place to ask questions. You should ask a new question where you explain what the problem is and provide sample data and expected results.